# What's the problem with that question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67266/please-help-review-and-suggest-my-element-diagram

It was obviously off-topic for RPG SE, but it was migrated there anyway… they rejected and locked it.

I don't understand.

Comment: Looks like a conversation needs to be had with the rpg.se mods...

Comment: Ironically, this is also a better question for RPG SE, not here.

Comment: No, the question started here, and I'm asking why it has been migrated in the first place.

Comment: @Lohoris Ah, see the initialism "OT" is a bad one. It can mean "On-Topic" or "Off-Topic", it did not make your position clear.

Comment: @Samuel edited, thanks

Comment: I'll have to ask you to explain the obvious part of it being off-topic for RPG.

Comment: @Samuel I'm sorry, it's "obvious" if you are a user of that site, if you aren't, I guess it isn't.

Comment: @Lohoris Does that make it unexplainable to non-active users of the site? I would suggest you give it a try. Since you're asking on Worldbuilding, not RPG.

Answer (score 1):

I flagged the question for migration because I felt it was better suited for RPG SE. Specifically it was a question of "[RPG rules or mechanics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)".

The question was asking for suggestions or improvements for the "15 elements system which may be used in my game and/or card game". That's not a Worldbuilding question in my opinion. It's also why it was closed, it's idea generation or brainstorming.

I'm not a mod, so I didn't actually migrate it, for that you'll need to ask the mod that moved it. I would assume they didn't blindly follow my suggestion, so must have agreed with the move.

Answer (score 1):

For starter, the question is off-topic for Worldbuilding SE since it was asking for ideas.

Without the suggestion to move the question to RPG SE, the idea would not have crossed my mind **but** I took the decision. I'm not a user there, so I don't know what is on topic. A quick glance at some questions gave me the idea that it was more appropriate there that here and the comments about the question (on the question page and in chat) also indicated this.

I was not sure if the question would be left open or closed once migrated but I was sure that RPG SE was a better fit for the question. I misjudged and we are back to square one. The question can still be edited and reopened in the future.